# No State appeared after country Selection in Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel

As I select the country the State Select Option doesn't appear and there are no states to select cities. 
Here's some text because stackoverflow is not allowing the below text because if too much code. It is still not allowing me because of it so here's some more text.

**AddressController**

```
use App\Country;
use App\State;
use App\City;
public function country()      //Fetches Country Perfectly
{
    $countries= Country::all();
    return view('address')->with('countries',$countries);
}

public function getStates($id)  //Not fetching states
{
    $states = State::where("country_id",$id)->get()->pluck("state_name","id");
    return response()->json($states);
}

public function getCities($id)   //Not fetching cities
{
    $cities= City::where("state_id",$id)->get()->pluck("city_name","id");
    return response()->json($cities);
}
```

**Route**

```
Route::get('/address/country', 'AddressController@country');
Route::get('/getStates/{id}','AddressController@getStates');
Route::get('/getCities/{id}','AddressController@getCities');
```

**address.blade**

```
<select name="country" id="country"> 
  <option value="">Select Country</option>
    @foreach ($countries as $country) 
        <option value="{{$country->ID}}">{{$country->name}}</option>  //fetching all the country
    @endforeach
 </select>
<select name="state" id="state">  // no result after country selection
</select>
<select name="city" id="city"> //no result as no state selected
</select>
//Here's a Javascript Code for the country.blade 
<script type="text/javascript">
 $('#country').change(function(){
    var cid = $(this).val();
    if(cid){
    $.ajax({
       type:"get",
       url:"{{ url('/state') }}/"+cid,
       success:function(res)
       {       
            if(res)
            {
                $("#state").empty();
                $("#city").empty();
                $("#state").append('<option>Select State</option>');
                $.each(res,function(key,value){
                    $("#getStates").append('<option value="'+key+'">'+value+'</option>');
                });
            }
       }

    });
    }
 });
 $('#state').change(function(){
    var sid = $(this).val();
    if(sid){
    $.ajax({
       type:"get",
       url:"{{url('/getCities')}}/"+sid,
       success:function(res)
       {       
            if(res)
            {
                $("#city").empty();
                $("#city").append('<option>Select City</option>');
                $.each(res,function(key,value){
                    $("#city").append('<option value="'+key+'">'+value+'</option>');
                });
            }
       }

    });
    }
 }); 
</script>
```

Here the Console Log

```
[Vue warn]: Error compiling template:

Templates should only be responsible for mapping the state to the UI. Avoid placing tags with side-effects in your templates, such as <script>, as they will not be parsed.

1172|  
1173|     <script type="text/javascript">
|     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
1174|             $('#country').change(function(){
|  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
1175|          var cid = $(this).val();
|  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
1176|          if(cid){
|  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
1177|          $.ajax({
|  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
1178|             type:"get",
|  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
1179|             url:"http://localhost/blog/public/getStates/"+cid,
|  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
1180|             success:function(res)
|  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
1181|             {       
|  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
1182|                  if(res)
|  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ 
1183|                  {
|  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
1184|                      $("#state").empty();
|  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
1185|                      $("#city").empty();
|  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
1186|                      $("#state").append('<option>Select State</option>');
|  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
1187|                      $.each(res,function(key,value){
|  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
1188|                          $("#state").append('<option 
value="'+key+'">'+value+'</option>');
|  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
1189|                      });
|  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
1190|                  }
|  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
1191|             }
|  ^^^^^^^^^^^^
1192|  
|  
1193|          });
|  ^^^^^^^^^^^
1194|          }
|  ^^^^^^^^^
1195|      });
|  ^^^^^^^
1196|      $('#state').change(function(){
|  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
1197|          var sid = $(this).val();
|  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
1198|          if(sid){
|  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
1199|          $.ajax({
|  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
1200|             type:"get",
|  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
1201|             url:"http://localhost/blog/public/getCities/"+sid,
|  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
1202|             success:function(res)
|  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
1203|             {       
|  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
1204|                  if(res)
|  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
1205|                  {
|  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
1206|                      $("#city").empty();
|  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
1207|                      $("#city").append('<option>Select City</option>');
|  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
1208|                      $.each(res,function(key,value){
|  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
1209|                          $("#city").append('<option 
value="'+key+'">'+value+'</option>');|^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
1210|                      });
|  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
1211|                  }
|  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
1212|             }
|  ^^^^^^^^^^^^
1213|  
|  
1214|          });
|  ^^^^^^^^^^^
1215|          }
|  ^^^^^^^^^
1216|      }); 
|  ^^^^^^^^
1217|  </script>
```

Comment: can you do `console.log(res)` on both ajax and share here ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the results before using pluck. Pluck is a method for laravel collections.

```
public function getStates($id) 
{
    $states = State::where("country_id",$id)->get()->pluck("state_name","id");
    return response()->json($states);
}

public function getCities($id)  
{
    $cities= City::where("state_id",$id)->get()->pluck("city_name","id");
return response()->json($cities);
}
```

Plus your states route should be:

```
Route::get('/getStates/{id}','AddressController@geStates');
```

Comment: can you show me few results using dd() may be.
dd($id);

then remove dd($id) and add dd($states);

I want to make sure first that we are passing the $id right. and then checking the response from Eloquent

Comment: I added  dd($id) instead of return function in getStates($id) but no response after country selection.

Comment: No no. Return to be same it is. dd() I said because I wanted to debug your code.

revert it. and show me output of     console.log(res) from browser.

Comment: Plus you need to check few things that value in id is being pass rightly, column names are same as in database. Waiting for console.log(res) output

Comment: Hi Osama, I have added console log and also tried try dd($id) and dd($states) in getStates($id)  but nothing show up on country selection

Comment: Oh man, it will not show anything in country selection, I am telling you these so we can tell what is wrong with the code. You need to show me the output of console log, it will contain the error you are facing. after you select the country , tell me the output from browser's console.

Comment: GET http://localhost/blog/public/address/%7B%7Burl('/getStates')%7D%7D/10 404 (Not Found) -- selecting country ID 10
GET http://localhost/blog/public/address/%7B%7Burl('/getStates')%7D%7D/2 404 (Not Found) -- selecting country ID 2
GET http://localhost/blog/public/address/%7B%7Burl('/getStates')%7D%7D/3 404 (Not Found) -- selecting country ID 3

Comment: /blog/public/address/%7B%7Burl('/getStates')%7D%7D/2
see this is one error, look at the url being generated

Comment: Yes, and How to rectify that? @osama?

Comment: use hard coded for now and see if it works.
in your ajax method for state change url value to:
```"http://localhost/blog/public/getStates/"+sid,```

Comment: Yes, that's what I exactly did @osama, and the select state appeared but the select option value of states is null and that is the only value

Comment: Show the console output again

Answer (score 0):

Here yo didn't pass the country id as argument for get state

```
Route::get('/getStates','AddressController@geStates');
```

So, add country id as argument

```
Route::get('/getStates/{id}','AddressController@geStates');
```

Also change `url:"{{ url('/state') }}/"+cid,` to `url:"{{ url('/getStates') }}/"+cid,`

Because the route is `getStates`

Also change `url:"{{url('/city')}}/"+sid,` to `url:"{{url('/getCities')}}/"+sid,`

Comment: try dd($states) in getStates($id) method.